# How do I use grep to get numbers larger than 50 from a txt file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, grep

I am relatively new to grep and unix. I am trying to get the names of people who have won more than 50 races from a txt file. So far the code I have used is, `cat file.txt|grep -E "[5-9][0-9]$"` but this is only giving me numbers from 50-99. How could I get it from 50-200. Thank you!!

| driver | races | wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some_Man | 90 | 160 |
| Some_Man | 10 | 80 |

the above is similar to the format of the data, although it is not tabulated.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form of code, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Rank    Country                    Driver                      Races       Wins
1           [United_Kingdom] Lewis_Hamilton        264       94
2          [Germany] Sebastian_Vettel                   254       53.

Comment: Could you please post these in your question with CODE TAGS for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: I have done so, if you need more help understanding the data let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use grep? you could use awk like this:
`awk '{if($[replace with the field number]>50)print$2}' < file.txt`

assuming your fields are delimited by spaces, otherwise you could use -F flag to specify delimiter.

if you must use grep, then it's regular expression like you did. to make it 50 to 200 you will do:
`cat file.txt|grep -E "(\b[5-9][0-9]|\b1[0-9][0-9])$"`

Answer (score 1):

Input:

```
Rank Country Driver Races Wins
1 [United_Kingdom] Lewis_Hamilton 264 94
2 [Germany] Sebastian_Vettel 254 53
3 [Spain] Fernando_Alonso 311 32
4 [Finland] Kimi_Raikkonen 326 21
5 [Germany] Nico_Rosberg 200 23
```

Awk would be a better candidate for this:

```
awk '$4>=50 && $4<=200 { print $0 }' file
```

Check to see if the fourth space delimited field ($4 - Change to what ever field number this actually is) if both greater than or equal to 50 and less than or equal to 200 and print the line ($0) if the condition is met